# what does it mean when it says your opponent "last played"?

Tags: words-with-friends

In the "Create a Game" tab (4th tab over, the "+" sign), Friends section, what does it mean when it says your opponent "last played"?

What constitutes a play playing last - when the have played a word in a game? signed it? visited the game but not played?

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing, it indicates that you "last played" if you wrote a message in chat, yet did not actually make a game move. So I think it marks you as "last played" at the time you log into the app, even if no move is made.

Comment: Been a while since I played, but this sounds accurate. It was more of a guide to see who would be more responsive. I would have friends on there, but last played forever ago. Those friends had tried the game, but didnt like it. A bit pointless starting a game with them. Friends that have even simply sent chat ingame are more likely to respond in games